# All Import Plugin - Update all posts after cron import

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, cron

I am having a bit of trouble with a function I am trying to write.

The idea behind it:

I am using WP All Import to import a CSV file on my server, this runs each day as a cron job and works as should.

I have set the logic of my function to 'get_post_meta' of a custom field inside my custom post type 'Listings', and if this returns empty, it adds the taxonomy term 'new', if returns true, it adds the taxonomy term 'used'. This works fine with the 'save_post'action, but only works when I go into each post after the import and hit 'update'. Is there any way to an update of all posts dynamically, so I don't have to update each one after the import. My code below that works on manual update. Thanks in advance!

```
function save_cp_term_meta( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
    $termshouldbe='new';

    $meta_value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'new_used_cat', true ); 
        if  (!empty( $meta_value )) {$termshouldbe='used';}
        else {} 

    wp_set_object_terms($post_id,$termshouldbe,'vehicle_condition',false);
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_cp_term_meta', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the import settings of your import. Under the **Configure Advanced Settings** tab, there is a checkbox **Increase speed by disabling do_action calls in wp_insert_post during import.**
Uncheck the checkbox and it should work automatically during import.

Comment: It's a feature by WP All Import. In each import you can disable any hooks which may have been implemented from various plugins or in functions.php like in the question. It helps to increase the speed of the import, which is usually preferred if the import file has a lot of entries. But in this case it needs to be turned off for the add_action hook to work.